# Передача параметров вне очереди | JS

Tags: javascript, функции

Как мне передавать параметры в функцию вне очереди? Например, у меня есть функция:

```
func(n_1 = '1', n_2 = '2', n_3 = '3')
```

Каждый из параметров имеет значение по умолчанию, поэтому мне нет нужды менять их. Тем не менее, возникает ситуация, когда мне надо изменить всего один параметр, который, допустим, идет последним. Переписывать все значения в конструктор не очень удобно.

Возникает вопрос, могу ли я в js сделать нечто подобное:

```
func(n_2 = '5')
```

Когда я пытался такое провернуть, то получил фатальную ошибку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оберните параметры в объект и делайте что хотите

```
func({n_1:'1', n_2:'2', n_3:'3'})

func({n_2:'5'})
```

хотите передавайте не хотите нет

```
func({})
```

По данносу принципу и существует такое понятие как параметры реквеста (запроса). По сути обычный объект в который вы записываете данные для дальнейшей работы.

Comment: Но если менять сигнатуру нежелательно, можно вызывать как `func(undefined, '5')`, хоть это и выглядит некрасиво и нелогично.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty `const Q = undefined; func(Q, Q, Q, '5');` — В том числе и сделав глобальный 'shortcut' в случае частой необходимости.